# Download file from asp webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on an asp webapplication and i want the user to be able to download a file from a page. So when the user clicks on the "download template file" button it will start downloading a copy of the file to the computer. How can i do that?

Comment: This question is not too clear. I think you can simply accomplish this with a hyperlink... or do you mean something else?

Comment: asp.net. The user has to download a template file. fill it and then upload it to another folder. The data from the Excel file is represented on the screen and then the user can upload data to databse. The reason for this i that the user is not allowed to add excel files that doesnt look like the template.

Answer (score 1):

To directly download file to your computer on button click just write this code on click event of button.

```
string filename = "~/File/yourFolder/"+ FileName;
string path = MapPath(filename);
byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Else if you are having hyperlink just give the path of file in navigate url

Answer (score 1):

> > The user has to download a template file.

As you mentioned in a comment that the user just needs to download the file. So, you must already have the url for the template file that is placed on the server. like

www.testwebsite.com/templatefile.xls

Add a simple link button in the website and in the href/Navigate URL add your template url. Whenever the user will click it, the file will be automatically downloaded.